# what is the order for the brainpool twisted curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Per [What is the difference between regular and "twisted" ECC curves?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42427/what-is-the-difference-between-regular-and-twisted-ecc-curves) I guess the brainpool twisted curves and the brainpool regular curves use the same point addition and point doubling algorithms.

[Domain-parameters.pdf#page=15](https://web.archive.org/web/20180408010242/http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/download/Domain-parameters.pdf#page=15) mentions the parameters for the 160-bit regular curve and the 160-bit twisted curve. For the regular curve it has a $p$ parameter and for the twisted curve it has a $Z$ parameter. I assume the $Z$ parameter is the prime number you need to do the modulo of after every operation.

What about the order $q$? Is the order the same for both curves?

If the curves are the same thing then couldn't one just treat them as aliases of one another? Like when you're randomly selecting $k$, between [$1, n-1$] and then multiplying the base point by that then you'd get the same answer no matter which curve you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What about the order $q$? Is the order the same for both curves?

Yes. This can be verified with the following commands:

```
openssl ecparam -name brainpoolP192t1 -genkey -text -noout -param_enc explicit

openssl ecparam -name brainpoolP192r1 -genkey -text -noout -param_enc explicit
```

This can be additionally verified by opening up [RFC5639](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5639), which lists $q$ for both the twisted and non-twisted curves and shows them to be the same.

> If the curves are the same thing then couldn't one just treat them as aliases of one another? Like when you're randomly selecting $k$, between [$1, n-1$] and then multiplying the base point by that then you'd get the same answer no matter which curve you used?

No. As demonstrated thusly:

```
# generate private keys
openssl ecparam -name brainpoolP192t1 -genkey -noout -out brainpoolP192t1.pem
openssl ecparam -name brainpoolP192r1 -genkey -noout -out brainpoolP192r1.pem

# generate public keys
openssl ec -in brainpoolP192t1.pem -pubout -out brainpoolP192t1.pub
openssl ec -in brainpoolP192r1.pem -pubout -out brainpoolP192r1.pub

# sign using brainpoolP192r1 
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign brainpoolP192r1.pem file.txt > signature.bin

# verify using brainpoolP192t1
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify brainpoolP192t1.pub -signature signature.bin file.txt
```

$p$ is the same as is $q$ but $a$ and $b$ are different.